# Sklearn: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scikit-learn

I am building a text classifier and I need some help. I have used the sklearn countvectorizer to create a bag of words but when I try to run it through an sklearn classifier it gives me the ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

```html
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 
from scipy import ndimage
from skimage import io
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

df = pd.DataFrame.from_csv('Training_Data.csv')

stopwordslist = frozenset(['and','the','-',',','by','/'])
count_vect = CountVectorizer(stop_words=stopwordslist)
Brandbag = count_vect.fit_transform(df.BrandName)
Brandbag.shape
#output is (6034, 1645). There are 6034 records in my df so that checks out.

df['Brandbag']=Brandbag

tempx = df['Brandbag'].head()

tempy = Y.head()

clf = MultinomialNB().fit(cesc,cescy)
```

The error is coming in a check array function when this line is called

`"array = np.array(array, dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy)"`

Comment: In your dataframe, you have saved a 2-d array in place of a column when you do `df['Brandbag']=Brandbag`. Thats the source of error.

Comment: would df['Brandbag']=Brandbag.values fix that? I want to add the values into the dataframe for easier train test split. Thanks for replying

Comment: I see what you are saying vivek. thanks

Comment: Btw vivek, I am actually classifying on 2 columns of text, hence 2 bags of words. What data structure should I use to pass in the X values in my classifier? a list of the 2d arrays?

Comment: It doesnt matter. Just join the two bag of words. The number of rows should be same. Only the features will increase. And then pass the new 2-d array of shape [number of records,  features1 + features2] to the classifier

Comment: By the way what if same word is in both the bags? Why not just join the two columns as one and then take bag of words.

Comment: yes vivek i just concatenated the strings of the the 2 columns and did a bag of words on both of them.

Comment: In case anyone wants a code snippet to resolve this issue: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/38269/59110